# Evaluate this limit involving e

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am solving this limit, but cannot find a satisfactory solution:
\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^\alpha)}{\alpha} 
\end{align}
I have tried substitution like $y = e^\alpha$ and $y = 1+ e^\alpha$ but nothing seems to work.

Comment: $\ln(1+e^\alpha)$ is about $\ln(e^\alpha) = \alpha$ for large $\alpha$.

Comment: The provided substitution gives$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\ln{(1+y)}}{\ln{(y)}}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\ln{(y)}+\overbrace{\ln{\left(1+\frac1y\right)}}^{\to0}}{\ln{(y)}}=1$$

Comment: Would $\dfrac{\ln(1+e^\alpha)}{\ln(0+e^\alpha)}$ help ?

Comment: How to proceed from this approach?

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+e^{\alpha})}{\alpha} \overset{\text{L.H.}}= \lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\frac{e^{\alpha}}{1+e^{\alpha}} $$ Dividing by $e^{\alpha}$ gives $$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{-\alpha} + 1}=\frac{1}{0+1} =1 $$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem):

> $$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(e^\alpha)}{\alpha}\leq\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^\alpha)}{\alpha}\leq \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(e^\alpha+e^\alpha)}{\alpha}\\\ln(e)\leq \lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+e^\alpha)}{\alpha}\leq \ln(e)+\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(2)}{\alpha}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\ln(1+e^a)=\ln(e^a(e^{-a}+1))=\ln(e^a)+\ln(e^{-a}+1)=a+\ln(e^{-a}+1)$$

Thus

$${\ln(1+e^a)\over a}=1+{\ln(e^{-a}+1)\over a}\to1+{\ln(0+1)\over\infty}=1+{0\over\infty}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Quite short, with some *asymptotic analysis*:

$1+\mathrm e^α\sim_\infty \mathrm e^α,\,$ so $\,\ln\bigl(1+\mathrm e^α\bigr)\sim_\infty \ln\bigl(\mathrm e^α\bigr)=α$, and therefore
$$\frac{\ln\bigl(1+\mathrm e^α\bigr)}{α}\sim_\infty\frac{α}{α}=1.$$